# Initialising a SwiftUI View via a Swift generic

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I'm adding Pull To Refresh to a SwiftUI based app.  To do this natively, I'm having to fall back to UIKit.  As I want to use Pull To Refresh across several tables and data models (with a shared Protocol), I want to use Generics.

I pass in the type of my dataModel, and I also want to pass in the type of the SwiftUI View I want to instantiate within the scrollView.

However, when I add in the generic type V, which I declare to support the Protocol 'View' I get a compilation error at the point the code tries to instantiate the view.

Type 'V' has no member 'init'

If I drop the generic type 'V', and hardcode a specific SwiftUI view type to instantiate instead, say DataView, it all works great - but that doesn't give me the flexibility in view type that I need.

How can I fix this compilation error, please?

```
import SwiftUI

struct GenericRefreshView<T, V>: UIViewRepresentable where T:ObservableObject, T:dataModel, V: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: T

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, regs: dataModel)
    }

    let size: CGSize

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        scrollView.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

        // *******************************************************************************
        let refreshVC = UIHostingController(rootView: V()) // Type 'V' has no member 'init'
        // *******************************************************************************

        refreshVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        scrollView.addSubview(refreshVC.view)

        return scrollView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {}

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var refreshScrollView: GenericRefreshView
        var dataModel: T

        init(_ refreshScrollView: GenericRefreshView, dataM: T) {
            self.refreshScrollView = refreshScrollView
            self.dataModel = dataM
        }

        @objc func handleRefreshControl (sender: UIRefreshControl) {
            self.dataModel.refresh()
            sender.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request it to be injected externally, like

```
struct GenericRefreshView<T, V>: UIViewRepresentable where T:ObservableObject, T:dataModel, V: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var dataModel: T
    let contentView: V                      // here !!
    // let builder: () -> V                 // alternate, as view builder

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, regs: dataModel)
    }

    let size: CGSize

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        scrollView.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

        let refreshVC = UIHostingController(rootView: self.contentView)    // here !!

   ...
```

**Update:** simplifying to avoid missed parts, here is a demo of usage

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GenericRefreshView(dataModel: TestViewModel(), 
                         contentView: Text("Demo"), 
                                size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    }
}

struct GenericRefreshView<T, V>: UIViewRepresentable where T:ObservableObject, V: View {

    @ObservedObject var dataModel: T     // << EnvironmentObject is internal, so cannot be inferred from input arguments, so not usable here
    let contentView: V
    let size: CGSize
```